# Decimals such as 0.1 and 0.2 equal 0.30000000000000004

Tags: java, swing, floating-point, decimal

I have a button that, when I press it I want it to update a label (which starts at 0.0) to + 0.1

I get the following:

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.79999999999999999
0.89999999999999999
0.99999999999999999
1.09999999999999999
```

The code I have is:

```
  double Number = Double.parseDouble(txtNumber.getText());
  double Generator = 0.1;
  Number = (Number + Generator);
  txtNumber.setText(Number + "");
```

I understand that the way computers work with numbers are not exactly 0.3 but more like 0.2999999... 
I just wanted a way to round the number so I can easily add 0.1(to)0.9 together without a mass of decimal places.

I have tried adding

```
Math.round((Number + Generator) * 100) / 100;
```

although it rounds it downwards to 0 so the label doesn't update.

Comment: Use `String.format` to generate the String version of the number.

Comment: (BTW, most Java coding standards mimic C standards and use leading lower-case letters for variable names, reserving Upper-Case for class names.)

Comment: See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).. (and hundreds of duplicates around SO).

Answer (score 4):

```
String myNumberString = String.format("%1.1d", Double.valueOf(myNumber));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want exact decimal addition, you need to use `BigDecimal` in place of `double`.

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(txtNumber.getText());
BigDecimal generator = new BigDecimal("0.1"); // The "" marks are important
number = number.add(generator);
txtNumber.setText(number.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Some decimals simply can't be represented by a `float` or `double` in such way the the difference is small enough. Simply because a computer uses the binary number system. For instance a computer will always fail to represent 1/3rd.

You can use a format, to round the number to one decimal using the following code:

```
double value = 0.3d;
String.format("%1.1d",value);
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is with the addition, not the internal representation.  It is possible to represent `0.3` with a `double`, then print that `double` and see `0.3`.  The problem is that it's not the same `double` that you get from adding `0.1` to `0.2`.

Comment: If I recall IEEE745 correctly, adding two numbers with the same exponent, will always be the correct addition. The problem however is that neither `0.1` neither `0.2` can be reprented correctly.